# Query for value matching in multiple arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing user experiences, table contains multiple records of same user

JSON example of data

```
{
    user_id : 1,
    location: 'india',
    company_id: 5,
    ...other fields
}
{
    user_id : 1,
    location: 'united kingdom',
    company_id: 6
    ...other fields
}
```

I want to run a query that gives me results of users who has worked in companies that satisfies IN condition of multiple arrays

E.g

`Array1 of company Id: 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10`

`Array2 of company Id: 2,6,50,100,12,4`

The query should return users who have worked in one of the companies from both arrays, so IN condition of both the arrays should be satisfied

I tried the following query with no luck

```
select * from <table> where company_id IN(5,7,8) and company_id IN(1,4,3)
```

and 2 records of a user with company_id 5 and 4 exists in table

Comment: Please tag one database system, not multiple database systems.

Comment: so what is your question? how to use IN or how to use OR?

Comment: There is no intersection in (5,7,8) and (1,4,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table my_table (user_id int, company_id int);

insert into my_table (user_id, company_id)
values (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 5);

select user_id from my_table where company_id in (5, 7, 8)
intersect
select user_id from my_table where company_id in (1, 4, 3);
```

As you described, you need to get intersection of users, who are working in two sets of companies.